# How to disable copy paste buttons in Edittext

Tags: android

I am developing an App in android, i want to disable copy paste buttons onLongClick,
I am using the following code:

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
        }

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it is showing error as
"The method setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(ActionMode.Callback) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (new ActionMode.Callback(){})".
I am searching for hours to get the solution. Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
import android.view.ActionMode.Callback;
```

to your imports

**OR**

if you have another `Callback` class already imported change

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
```

to

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new android.view.ActionMode.Callback() {
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error in above method because the method is included in API Level 13+ and your current compilation version may be set to lower.

**Right Click on project** -> **properties** -> **"Android Tab"** -> **select api level 13 or greater**.

If you wants backward support, you can try these tricks.

1)

```
OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //since nothing is in here, nothing will happen.  

        return true;
    }
};
```

2)

```
edtPassword.setLongClickable(false);
```

3) IN XML

```
android:longClickable="false"
```

**NOTE :**

The method you are trying will only works with API level 13+. But these tricks will work with lower aloso

Answer (score 0):

I found one hack. It's working charm:

```
OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //since nothing is in here, nothing will happen.  
        setEnabled(false);
        setEnabled(true);
        return false;
    }
};
```

Do same for onClick event of OnClickListener.